# Cannot drag and drop a file into emacs and open it in windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, emacs

I cannot drag and drop a file into emacs and open it!  Just nothing happened. The problem appear since Win7.
And I copy these file to another computer, it works well.

What suppose to fixed it?

This is my version of emacs,and I start the emacs from the runemacs.exe

GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2014-05-22 on ALIMANTADO
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

Try running *emacs.exe* instead of *runemacs.exe*.
Worked for me but not perfect because then there's the irritating cmd window..

Comment: Works for me. I run Emacs 27.2 in Windows 10 natively.